# Why do we use `As foo (geom)` and not `As geom`

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

In the query below, why do we use `As foo (geom)` and not `As geom`? What does `foo()` do?

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) AS srid, ST_SRID(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326)) as srid_new
FROM (
    VALUES (
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((70 20, 71 21, 71 19, 70 20))', 4269)), 
        (ST_Point(1,2)
    )
) As foo (geom);
```

Using `As geom` gives the error:

```
ERROR:  function st_srid(record) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_SRID(geom) AS srid, ST_SRID(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326)...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`As foo` is an alias for the subquery, and the `(geom)` attached to it is the column name in it. SQL requires an alias for every subquery. Find an example in the [manual in the chapter **Subqueries**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES).

The same goes for a `VALUES` expression used in this place. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html):

> Syntactically, VALUES followed by expression lists is treated as equivalent to:

```
 SELECT select_list FROM table_expression
```

Comment: Why must the subquery's alias be a function `foo()` instead of `foo`? In the query `SELECT ST_AsSVG(geom,1,5) As SVG_Relative
FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2 48, 0 51)', 4326) As geom) AS foo;`, the alias is simply `foo`.

Comment: @Nyxynyx The alias is not a function. It just so happens that parentheses are required if you append column names after the table alias. Your example in the comment supplies a column name as alias to the value directly, so one can omit `(geom)`. You could still append `foo(other_name)` to overrule column name `geom` declared inside the subquery expression.